# Why Windows7 wont let me access Samba share, configured this way?

Tags: samba

```
 $ smbd --version
 Version 3.5.4
```

Config:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = SHAREME
   security = share
   hosts allow =  192.168.232.2
   load printers = yes
   guest account = nobody
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 50
   domain master = no
   local master = yes
   os level = 35
   null passwords = true
   username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
   name resolve order = hosts wins bcast
   dns proxy = no 

[up]
   comment = smb
   path = /var/smb/
   public = yes
   writable = yes
   browseable = yes
   force user = nobody
   force group = nogroup
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
   available = yes
```

Path:

```
ls -la /var/smb/
total 4
drwxrw-rw-  2 root root    6 Aug 31 14:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 Sep 18 19:51 ..
```

smbusers:

```
#   Unix_name = SMB_name1 SMB_name2 ...
root = Administrator admin
nobody = guest pcguest smbguest
```

Windows7: access forbidden to whole \192.168.232.2 (ever no resource listing).
After turning security = share, got advance: \192.168.232.2\up is visible, but still can't be accessed. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, perhaps you forgot to make the directory /var/smb searchable by anyone other than root.
This might help:

```
# chmod +x /var/smb
```